# Hazelcast and ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: hazelcast

I am going to use Hazelcast for one of my projects. I wonder if creating a new Hazelcast client instance for every request is feasible. Do I get a performance hit because of this or is this a general practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast clients are fully threadsafe and you should not recreate a client per request. Create a common instance and share it through all requests.